# Login and password in one array

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I want to create an application that takes users input login and password, and, the main problem, saves this data in an array. Due to the task requirements, it must be a one dimensional array. Something like this:

- `array = { {login1, password1}, {login2, password2} etc.}`

  or
- `array = {login1, password1, etc..}`

I'm not really sure about the teacher's expectations as they are not precised.

When trying to log in, the program has to take the data from the array and check whether input of login and password registered before are correct.

And my teacher was saying something about "paired values in array". Can someone explain how to make it and how does it works? Example code would be the best.

Comment: How should we know what your teacher expects? What was the actual task? And what did you try? We´re not doing your job here.

Comment: I don't understand your indignation, sir. All things that you need to know and I know is written. "How should we know what your teacher expects?" - I ddin't ask for that and I even pointed out "I'm not really sure about the teacher's expectations as they are not precised." so I'm giving all I know. "What was the actual task?" - It's written above. "We´re not doing your job here." - I'm not asking you  to do the job, I pointed out: "Can someone explain how to make it and how does it works? Example code would be the best." No offence but it's time for comprehension reading.

Answer (score -1):

When you have to use an array try like this:

`var logins = new (string, string)[10];`

- `var` is a reserved keyword, the compiler will recongnize the correct type for you.
- `logins` name of the variable.
- `new` makes a new instance of the given type.
- `(string, string)` is a special type in c#. In this case its a tuple that contains two strings.
- `[10]` is for the array. 10 can be a other value and can be changed to the count for the logins.

If you are using a version of c# below 7.0 try like this:

`var logins = new Tuple <string, string>[10];`

- `Tuple<>` is a datatype which can take up to 8 generic types.
- `<string, string>` generic type parameters for the `Tuple`.

And a other solution with a anonymous datatype:

`var logins = new [] { new { name = "peter", password = "topsecret" }, new { name = "klaus", password = "12345" } };`

- `new [] { ... }` creates a array with filled data.
- `new { ... }` creates a anonymous type.
- `name = "string"` is part of the anonymous type.

You access the data in this way: `logins[0].name;`.

Comment: That won´t even compile.

Comment: I typed it with my handy. It seems correct (execpt of the `;`). Whats missing?

Comment: ValueTuple need 1) C#7.x and 2) the ValueTuple nuget.

Comment: Also, that's not an array, a tuple is not an array. And var is not a "generic datatype" is a reserved word.

Comment: Why its not an array? O.o

Comment: I edited the answer, is it now better for you @Luis?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and your forbearance for beginners like me. I belive it will be useful as it looks like. I'm gonna try this way and thank you again later.

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, then accept the answer. And maybe vote it up. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = new[] { userName, password };
```

userName and password are string variables where you saved the user name and the user password.

You can access the user name:

```
array[0];
```

and the password:

```
array[1];
```

Comment: Hmmm... I think I will have to create a for loop here. Because it should be automatic for my logins to be saved in an array. Writing "array[2] = Console.Readline() and so on, has no sense. And use array length to push them. I'll try that.